# How do I TRANSLATE relative to active/cursor?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

so, what i wanna do is translate a part relative to an active point/3d cursor while keeping the dimensions of said part constant.

on this pic, the red line highlights the path i want to translate ALONG (line connecting the center of the part i want to translate and the point i want to translate relative to).

[image]

i can move a single vertex relative to a point with relative scaling- but it doesn't work with more than one vertex. it scales the part i want to move too.

also, the above pic is just a SIMPLE example of what i want to do. what i want is not a solution to that PARTICULAR problem - but one that applies to everything. thanks :]

Comment: You can scale with pivot as cursor, and then put the pivot at median again and scale it back down

Comment: yes...that's one way. what i do is put TWO vertices at the center of the part i want to move, relative scale one of those vertices, then select the part with the other vertex as active and snap the whole thing to the scaled vertex. too much work but it preserves the scale PERFECTLY whereas scaling, for instance, by 3 and descaling by 3 doesn't (0.333...). neither is an ideal solution as you won't see the end results while editing - but "it's something." lol thanks!

Comment: You are a brilliant

Comment: In case like this it could be done with Hook modifer (or maybe even armature). Probably it's not the best solution for what you really want to do as there's no information about that. No way to do that with simple scale

Answer (score 1):

Ideally what you are looking for is a translate using spherical coordinates, which is not currently supported; but it could certainly be added using a small script, see https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?168749-How-to-set-polar-coordinates&p=1485444&viewfull=1#post1485444

You could make a request, probably in the bug tracker, and see if anyone shows an interest, or if it is worth the effort, learn just enough about Python and Blender's add-on system to do it yourself.